# window.onload not working chrome dev console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, window.location, window.onunload

`window.onload` doesn't seem to run the specified function in the chrome `console` and I can't seem to find anyone with the same problem.

Code:

```
function preStart() {
    console.log("Hello");
}
window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
window.onload = preStart;
```

When ran the `window.location` successfully runs but `"preStart"` does not. Any help with this would me much appreciated.

Edit - Ben Hanna says `.onload` will not activate because the page is changed which is fine but is there a solution to this? (where the function runs after the page changes)

Answer (score 0):

This code will never hit the `onload` event if you're changing the `location` to navigate away to another page.

Update: You could do something like this.

```
function preStart() {
   // You can run a function like this before navigating
   console.log("Hello");
   window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';
   // You can't run a function once you've navigated to Google
   // because you can't execute arbitrary scripts on pages/domains
   // that you don't own.
}

// preStart will be executed when the `onload` event fires
window.onload = preStart;
```

Comment: Ok but is there a different way I could do this to make it work?

Comment: If you're meaning for the `onload` event to fire before you change `location` then you could just put that statement in the `preStart` function after the `console.log`.

Comment: Sorry but I am kind of new to JavaScript, but I am trying to run a function after a new page has loaded. I don't understand what you mean by "put that statement in the preStart function after the console.log", do you mean: `function preStart() {
    console.log("Hello");
 window.onload = preStart();
};
window.location = 'https://www.google.com/';` which doesn't seem to work.